# how add exif data when capture a photo in android

Tags: android, geolocation, exif

i am new to android please tell to that,how to add EX-IF data(lat,lng) to a capture photo and i implemented by using MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE,but it gives lat:0.0
lng:0.0

Comment: can you enabled gps on testing device?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html